# Побитовые операции в Lua 5.1

Tags: lua, битовые-операции

Нужен пример 2 фунцкий. Первая заменяет в числе по позиции значние бита и возвращает новое число. Вторая достаёт по индексу бит. Числа на вход всегда uint16.

```lua
--- return new value as number
local functioн setBit(valueNum, indexNum, bitValNum)
    return modifiedValue
end

--- return 0 or 1
local gunction getBitValue(valueNum, indexNum)
end
```

Comment: [тыц](http://lua-users.org/wiki/BitwiseOperators)

Comment: ```function hasbit(x, p)
  return x % (p + p) >= p       
end

function setbit(x, p)
  return hasbit(x, p) and x or x + p
end

function clearbit(x, p)
  return hasbit(x, p) and x - p or x
end

function test()
  --- 1101
  local v = 13
  local r = clearbit(v, 2)
  -- 12 ?
  -- 9
  return r
end 
```

Comment: set/clear разобрался

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку !

Answer (score 1):

```
function bit(p)
  return 2 ^ (p - 1)  -- 1-based indexing
end

function hasbit(x, p)
  return x % (p + p) >= p       
end

function setbit(x, p)
  return hasbit(x, p) and x or x + p
end

function clearbit(x, p)
  return hasbit(x, p) and x - p or x
end
```